# I recently got on a new team and trying to setup the project requirements. How to upgrade existing maven version 3.1.1 to 3.3.9

Tags: maven

I recently got on a new team and trying to setup the project requirements. Currently, I had Maven 3.1.1 on my system and I need Maven 3.3.9. If any one can tell me how to upgrade the version of maven, I would appreciate it. (I'm working on windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple - download maven from the official distribution archive 
that is available at https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/. After that follow installation guide from maven documentation available at https://maven.apache.org/install.html.
Just remember that Maven 3.3.9 requires at least Java version 7.